# "No module named 'requests'" error executing Python from cron job on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cron

I've been trying to trigger a python script from a cron job on my macos.
I enabled cron in the list of apps that are granted the right to access the Full Disk.

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nicolas/Documents/Development/Journal/databases.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, json, requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

crontabe -e:

```
0 * * * *  cd /Users/nicolas/Documents/Development/Journal/; python3 create_json.py >> /Users/nicolas/Documents/Development/Journal/Log.txt 2>&1
```

create_json.py first lines:

```
import os, json, datetime, time, subprocess
import functions
import databases, trades, journal_types, journal_years, journal_months
from config import folder_path

#Generate the list of Databases ID or take it from file if exists
def createDatabasesID():
  databases_id_path = folder_path+'databases_id.json'
  if functions.jsonEmpty(databases_id_path):
    databases_id_list = databases.getDatabases()
    functions.createJSON(databases_id_list, os.path.abspath(databases_id_path))
    print(f'Databases ID list done')
  else:
    print(f'Databases ID list already exists')
```

Then first lines of databases:

```
import os, json, requests
from config import notion_secret, database_names, folder_path
```

It works great when I trigger it manually from the folder, but not from the cron job.

Edit #01:
Now that the cronjob properly executes my python, it fails at automatically commiting files on github, **while it works great when I execute from folder**.
The error I get is:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

In my create_json.py, I have this line:

```
def commitGit(last_script):
  script_path = 'commit_git.sh'
  subprocess.call(['bash', script_path])
```

It executes the commit_git.sh:

```
cd public
git add -A
git commit -m "Commit"
git push origin main
```

Comment: You didn't show your crontab entry. You didn't show your script. So we neither know what you actually started nor how you started it.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I did not show because it seemed irrelevant to me. The script starts by importing requests that is available on my computer but the script executed by the cron job failed to import it while it works perfectly when I trigger the script from the folder the classic way

Comment: You still didn't show the line in your crontab and you still didn't show the start of your script. Please click [edit] and put those two things in your question. Thank you.

Comment: Done, main description edited

Comment: Change your script so that the very first thing it does is `print(sys.executable)` and `print(sys.path)` and run it from your folder then from crontab and see if you are running the same Python interpreter and looking in the same places for your packages.

Comment: From folder (had to add import sys at the top of the script):
/usr/local/bin/python3
['/Users/nicolas/Documents/Development/Journal', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

Comment: From cron:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
['/Users/nicolas/Documents/Development/Journal', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Comment: So you can presumably see you are running PSF Python 3.10 from your folder but Apple Python 3.9 from crontab. So you must have a different PATH (or other environment in cron). Maybe use the full path to Python in your crontab, e.g. `0 * * * *  cd somewhere; /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python3 somescript`

Comment: Thanks for your help.
That was indeed the catch. Works well now.

Comment: Hi Mark, my script still fails because of the cron job, should I create a new topic? My script automatically commits pages into github and it does not work from the job but works from folder.

Comment: Ideally you would click [edit] and update your question with your latest code and the latest, corresponding error messages.

Comment: The `bash` script doesn't go through your normal login process, probably doesn't have any environment variables defined (that `git` normally uses, such as API_KEY) or have a decently defined PATH or necessarily run from the directory you normally run it from. You need to add PATH and/or environment variables and be more specific about where you are changing directory to - rather than just `cd public` which might be anywhere.

Comment: Perfect thanks.
For the record, I had to put the absolute path but also load my ssh key.
Works great now.